# python subprocess as normal user

Tags: python, root, sudo

I have a script that needs to be run as a super user:

```
$ sudo ./python-script.py
```

Within this script, I do some other things that *do not* require super user privileges.

```
$ os.mkdir('somefolder')
```

What is the best/most efficient way of creating the directory as non-root user? Should I let the script make the directory as root user, and then change permissions on it?

Comment: do you need root permissions after creating the directory?

Comment: Not necessarily... https://github.com/sudojesse/easy-vhost-add/blob/master/new-vhost.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.mkdir` does allow you to specify the permissions explicitly:

```
os.mkdir(path [, mode=0777])
```

And you also have the option of running `os.chown` to set the user and group

```
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

You can probably get the original user like this (but it might be platform specific?)

```
import os
original_user = os.environ.get('SUDO_USER')
original_uid = os.environ.get('SUDO_UID')
original_gid = os.environ.get('SUDO_GID')
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get a uid or gid of the non-root user?

Comment: pardon my ignorance but does the ... within the mkdir call in the example above represent the Ellipsis object?

Comment: @cravoori: that is a straight copy paste from the docs. Its a place holder for the args which are explained below.

Comment: @cravoori: i edited it because it might be confusing if ppl dont know its a docstring